# ALL the restricted function, variable and expression of PHP?

Tags: php

I want to know where can I find ALL the restricted function, variable and reserved expression of PHP?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/):

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.php

If I understood your question correctly.

Comment: @Shehi, sorry :D  and I even had to fill out a captcha (no idea why...).

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.php